# UITableView - Setting cornerRadius to layer doesn't work for top corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to make a pretty UITableView, trying to make the following:

```
self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.tableView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,0.5f);
self.tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = .5f;
self.tableView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.5f;
```

And I get the following result:

[image]

Why my UITableView's top corners aren't rounded?

Comment: Please put more info on how you are implementig this table view: is it a grouped table view? Are you using custom cells?

Comment: Set self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me you are doing well but there is short of this code. So please try to Implement this one. I think you wanna like this ..See in below image
[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```